# How to notate all integers $\gt 1$ except products of $2, 3 , 5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

What is a notation for all whole numbers greater than $6$ which are not a product of $2, 3 , 5$? $7$ would the first, then $11, 13, \ldots$ also $7\times 7$ or $11\times 11$ would be included.

As a clarification, start of the sequence would be:

$$7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 89, 91, 97, 101,\ldots$$

Comment: $S = \{ \text{all whole numbers > 6 etc.}\}$?

Comment: Would $\large 2\cdot 7$ be in the set?

Comment: 2*7 is a product of 2, so not. Maybe my question terms are not right if this made a confusion...

Comment: @MarkokraM: Your phrasing could be interpreted as "numbers that are products **only** of the numbers 2, 3, 5".

Comment: I'm using "except products" and "not a product" there but you might be right. I hope my sequence sample clarifies it better. Gonna prefer numbers over words in future :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the positive integers that are not 5-smooth. These numbers are also called 7-rough. Alternatively, if you want a set notation, $$S = \{n \in \mathbb N_{>1}: 2 \nmid n, 3 \nmid n, 5 \nmid n\}$$

works.

Comment: I would use $:$ instead of $|$ for "such that" here, as it could be confused with all those "divides".

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Good suggestion.

Comment: Is "not 5-smooth" same as 7-rough?

Comment: @MarkokraM Yes, correct. I shall edit that in.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers are correct, but here is an attempt at a compact approach:
$$\{n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}:\gcd(n,30)=1\}$$

Comment: you can even leave out $n\geq 6$ :)

Comment: @sranthrop: Haha, very nice observation :)

Comment: Alternatively use $\mathbb N_{>1}$, which is even more compact.

Comment: This is efficient but I wonder if it would leave the intended meaning unclear to the reader. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: No disagreement there, just having fun with an alternative approach.

Comment: 30 could be explained by 2*3*5 so it would be in direct visual sync with the question. I guess you can get a set of similar: gcd(n,34)=1 for all numbers that doesn't divide with 2 and 17?

Comment: @MarkokraM Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 7):

You could use $(\mathbb{N}+6) \setminus (2\mathbb{Z} \cup 3\mathbb{Z} \cup 5\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 3):

The following also works :

$$\{n\mid n\in\mathbb N,n\not=1,n^2\equiv 1,19\pmod{30}\}$$

Comment: That works, nice find, +1, but how did you find it?

Comment: @wythagoras: Just because I've found the values of $n^2\pmod{30}$ for some question a long ago. I just found them in my notebook:)

Answer (score 0):

A modification of **Zev Chonoles**'s answer,
$$\{n|n\in\mathbb N_{>1},30|n^{8}-1\}$$
Which follows from Euler's Totient Theorem.